# Scroll Problem on mobile device in my shopify website

Tags: css, shopify, liquid

If you scroll with your fingers from the product section, the scroll is not working on mobile devices. How to fix this?

Website : https://www.touchshoptoys.com/products/robottoys

I want to smooth scrolling.its tough to go add to cart button using mobile

Comment: It scrolls on FF.

Comment: which mobile browser (and version) are you finding this issue with?

Comment: every mobile device

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.